# My Git contributions aren't updated on my GitHub profile

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a problem with updating my git contribution to GitHub when I'm on a new branch, that isn't main.

For short I have 2 branches: main and magical-chat-app. When I make commits on magical-chat-app, it does show nothing on my profile. But when I make a commit on my main branch, it does show up.

I already verified my user.name and user.email, and they are the correct ones. I didn't forked the project.

Here are the links:

```
https://github.com/WebDices/chat-application/tree/main

https://github.com/WebDices/chat-application/tree/magical-chat-app

https://github.com/WebDices
```

Comment: Note: `git commit` is not the same as `git push`!

Comment: The commits are pushed in both branches. I added the files, committed them, and in the end I pushed. You can see it on the above links.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:WebDices/chat-application.git
Cloning into 'chat-application'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 9 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (12/12), done.

$ cd chat-application/

$ git log
commit 85bee60d168759cd0b610850e2a77bce9e937dbb (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: WebDices <webdices@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 19 22:32:38 2021 +0200

    commit test

commit 946e1a7fc87dea46cd741b4fdc99cdc5f1e099c4
Author: Alexandru Buruiană <53376915+WebDices@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 16 18:33:46 2021 +0200

    Initial commit

$ git checkout magical-chat-app
Branch 'magical-chat-app' set up to track remote branch 'magical-chat-app' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'magical-chat-app'

$ git log
commit 730d802cc46e8241cc831bd145265db7826a02ab (HEAD -> magical-chat-app, origin/magical-chat-app)
Author: WebDices <webdices@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 19 22:31:03 2021 +0200

    first commit

commit b3b4701501f21142636e05c1adbf1822fc34ceaf
Author: Alexandru Buruiana <webdices@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 19 22:26:30 2021 +0200

    first commit

commit 946e1a7fc87dea46cd741b4fdc99cdc5f1e099c4
Author: Alexandru Buruiană <53376915+WebDices@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 16 18:33:46 2021 +0200

    Initial commit
```

> does show nothing on my profile

Not sure what "profile" you are talking about. Whatever that is, perhaps there is a delay before *it* gets synchronized?

Comment: On the green square it doesn't show all the contributions. If you see the last green square, it says just 1 contribution (on the main branch), but it doesn't show what I did on the magical-chat-app branch. As it didn't exist.